# Can't get WebApplicationContext object from ContextRegistry.GetContext(): Resource handler for the 'web' protocol is not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, webforms, spring.net

I'm stucked in configuring my web.config file under a web forms project in order to get an instance of WebApplicationContext (at Global.asax) and then being able to use scope="application | session | request"

```xml
<sectionGroup name="spring">
    <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebContextHandler, Spring.Web"/>
    <section name="objects" type="Spring.Context.Support.DefaultSectionHandler, Spring.Core" />
</sectionGroup>

<spring>
    <context type="Spring.Context.Support.WebApplicationContext, Spring.Web">
        <resource uri="~/Configuration/Spring.xml" />
    </context>
</spring>

<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="Spring.Web.Support.PageHandlerFactory, Spring.Web"/>
</httpHandlers>

<httpModules>
    <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web"/>
</httpModules>
```

I'm then trying to add the WebApplicationContext to my Application object, in order to cosume on any .aspx page;

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Exception happens on next line!
    Application.Add("ContainerID", ContextRegistry.GetContext());
}
```

Exception I'm getting is;

```
"Error creating context 'spring.root': Resource handler for the 'web' protocol is not defined. Spring.NET"
```

I have have spent some time googling, but no success. Ive found at Spring.NET documentation;
"In web applications Spring provides
a WebApplicationContext implementation which is configured by adding a custom HTTP module and HTTP
handler to your Web.config file. See the section on Web Configuration for more details." But it is in no way happening.

Please, could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the spring.net container is not initialized on `Application_Start`.

and btw, why would you want to add the container in the `Application` bucker? It sounds like an antipattern to me...

Comment: Yeah @Jaguar, thanx very much!!! It really did the trick!!! I'm just trying more times out to ensure I will have no other problems and then accept your answer!!! Look how weird it is; if I do not declare de httpHandler/httpModule, I can initialize the container at the App_Start and use it normally but I got an XmlApplication context instead of an WebAppContext. Thats why I though there was a problem. Thank you again bro!!! Soon I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Jaguar You initialize the Spring container on `Application_Start` to run business rules that need to run before the application runs, i.e. update static singleton data.

Comment: @RenatoGama What did you do to solve your problem? Remove `ContextRegistry.GetContext()` from your `Application_Start`?

Comment: @Exegesis sorry but this is a problem I solved almost 10 years ago, I don't remember the exact solution :/

Answer (score 1):

Add this to system.webServer config node:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="Spring" preCondition="integratedMode" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web"/>
</modules>
```

If you use integratedMode in IIS7